# wrapping socket with websocket

Tags: webserver, websocket, ada

Is it possible to use a webserver with websockets as a wrapper to another server to pass messages from the "real server" to a web client and back?

Im curious of this as I have a game server written in Ada that has an OS-tied client. I would like to swap this client to a webclient based on Javascript, so that the game can be played in a normal browser. What can be done?

Comment: that depends on the webserver

Comment: Google "html5 remote desktop"

Comment: Ah then it appears to work nice. I will probably use a ruby/sinatra webserver in ruby since its flexible and im going to use it for other parts of the web interface aswell.

Comment: I added my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code in ruby to wrapp my sockets. The code was adapted from [em-websocket-proxy](https://github.com/mcolyer/em-websocket-proxy). There might be some specifics for my project in it but generally switching remote_host and remote_port and connecting to localhost:3000 should set you up with a new connection to your server through a websocket.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'em-websocket'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'thin'
require 'haml'
require 'socket'


class App < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
        haml :index
    end
end

class ServerConnection < EventMachine::Connection

  def initialize(input, output)
    super
    @input = input
    @output = output
    @input_sid = @input.subscribe { |msg| send_data msg+ "\n" }
  end

  def receive_data(msg)
    @output.push(msg)
  end

  def unbind
    @input.unsubscribe(@input_sid)
  end

end

# Configuration of server
options = {:remote_host => 'your-server', :remote_port => 4000}

EventMachine.run do   

  EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => '0.0.0.0', :port => 8080) do |ws|
    ws.onopen {
      output = EM::Channel.new
      input = EM::Channel.new

      output_sid = output.subscribe { |msg| ws.send msg; }

      EventMachine::connect options[:remote_host], options[:remote_port], ServerConnection, input, output

      ws.onmessage { |msg| input.push(msg)}

      ws.onclose {
        output.unsubscribe(output_sid)
      }
    }
  end

  App.run!({:port => 3000})   

end
```

Enjoy! And ask if you have questions.

Answer (score 3):

That is the purpose of [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify). It is designed to bridge between WebSocket clients and regular TCP servers. It was created as part of the [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) which is an HTML5 VNC app that can connect to normal VNC servers. However, websockify is generic and there are now many other projects using it.

*Disclaimer*: I created websockify and noVNC.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily accomplish this by using AWS:

http://libre.adacore.com/tools/aws/

There's support for websockets in AWS, and you can make use of it's excellent socket (AWS.Net) packages for normal socket support.

Answer (score 1):

Websockets are, contrary to what some people believe, not pure sockets. The raw data is encapsulated and masked by the websocket protocol which isn't widely supported yet. That means an application which wasn't designed for it, you can't communicate with it directly via web sockets.

When you have an application which uses a protocol based on normal sockets, and you want to communicate with it with websockets, there are two options.

Either you use a websocket gateway which does the unpacking / packing of the websocket traffic and forwards it as pure socket traffic to the application. This has the advantage that you needn't modify the application, but it has the disadvantage that it also masks the real IP address of the client which might or might not be a problem for certain applications.

Or you implement websocket in your application directly. This can be done by having two different ports the server listens to, one for normal connections and one for websocket connections. Any data which is received or sent through the websocket-port is sent through your websocket implementation before sending / after receiving it, and otherwise processed by the same routines.

Answer (score 1):

THe Kaazing HTML5 Gateway is a great way of bringing your TCP-based protocol to a web client. The Kaazing gateway basically takes your protocol running on top of TCP and converts it to WebSocket so you can access the protocol in the client. You would still need to write a JavaScript protocol library for the protocol that your back end uses. But if you can work with the protocol on top of TCP, then it's not hard to do it with JavaScript.